# PyTorch and CUDA driver

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

I have CUDA 9.2 installed. For example:

```
(base) c:\>nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2018 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Wed_Apr_11_23:16:30_Central_Daylight_Time_2018
Cuda compilation tools, release 9.2, V9.2.88
```

I installed PyTorch on Windows 10 using:

```
conda install pytorch cuda92 -c pytorch
pip3 install torchvision
```

I ran the test script:

```
(base) c:\>python
Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Mar 29 2018, 13:32:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from __future__ import print_function
>>> import torch
>>> x = torch.rand(5, 3)
>>> print(x)
tensor([[0.7041, 0.5685, 0.4036],
        [0.3089, 0.5286, 0.3245],
        [0.3504, 0.8638, 0.1118],
        [0.6517, 0.9209, 0.6801],
        [0.0315, 0.1923, 0.8720]])
>>> quit()
```

So for, so good.  Then I ran:

```
(base) c:\>python
Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Mar 29 2018, 13:32:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import torch
>>> torch.cuda.is_available()
False
>>>
```

Why did PyTorch say CUDA was not available?

The GPU is a compute capability 3.0 Quadro K3000M:

```
(base) C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVSMI>nvidia-smi.exe 

Mon Oct 01 16:36:47 2018 
NVIDIA-SMI 385.54 Driver Version: 385.54 
-------------------------------+----------------------+---------------------- 
GPU Name TCC/WDDM              | Bus-Id Disp.A        | Volatile Uncorr. 
ECC Fan Temp Perf Pwr:Usage/Cap| Memory-Usage         | GPU-Util Compute M. 
0 Quadro K3000M WDDM           | 00000000:01:00.0 Off | 
N/A N/A 35C  P0 N/A / N/A      | 29MiB / 2048MiB      | 0% Default
```

Comment: Can you provide the output of `nvidia-smi` ?

Comment: (base) C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVSMI>nvidia-smi.exe
Mon Oct 01 16:36:47 2018

 NVIDIA-SMI 385.54                 Driver Version: 385.54
-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------
 GPU  Name            TCC/WDDM | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC
 Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M.

   0  Quadro K3000M      WDDM  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A
 N/A   35C    P0    N/A /  N/A |     29MiB /  2048MiB |      0%      Default

Answer (score 1):

Ever since https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/releases/tag/v0.3.1, PyTorch binary releases had removed support for old GPUs' with CUDA capability 3.0.  According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA, the compute capability of Quadro K3000M is 3.0.

Therefore, you might have to build pytorch from source or try other packages.  Please refer to this thread for more information --  https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/pytorch-no-longer-supports-this-gpu-because-it-is-too-old/13803.

Answer (score -1):

PyTorch official call for using CUDA 9.0 and I would suggest the same. In other cases, there are sometimes build issues which leads to 'CUDA not detected'.So, when using PyTorch its best to use CUDA 9.0 and CuDnn 7. I'll add a link where you can easily install Cuda 9.0 and CuDnn 7.

https://yangcha.github.io/CUDA90/

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem, you have to check on NVIDIA control panel that your card is selected by default.